# CPU frequency maxed (but little CPU load) with external USB audio interface

Tags: usb, sound, cpu

I'm on 18.04, i7-8850H, powersave governor. When I connect my external USB audio interface (Behringer UMC440HD), and especially when I try to play any sound through it, the CPU frequency starts oscillating around 4+ GHz while the reported CPU load is low. This leads to high fan speed and unnecesary power draw. Any help very appreciated.